# fopen Data save in Database

Tags: php, mysql, fopen, explode

I want to save datas from an fopen link into my database .. i get some help to use explode .. for that i got some code which should work .. but it doesn´t.

i have an error somewhere but i cannot find it (i cut out the database connection part to save space on screen)

stg_interface have the columns "uid, tan, kid, ziel, banner, verdienst, preis, aufendhalt, menge, reload, sponsor, werbeart, status, beschreibung, mailtext, gueltig"

```
// ***** Database Connection ***** //

// Interfacedaten laden
$sql_interface = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stg_interface WHERE sponsor = 'allads4you' AND Werbeart = 'forcedbanner' LIMIT 1");
$output_interface = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_interface);

$id_betreiber = $output_interface['id_betreiber'];
$id_seite = $output_interface['id_seite'];
$schnittstellencode = $output_interface['schnittstellencode'];
$max_reload = $output_interface['max_reload'];
$max_verguetung = $output_interface['max_verguetung'];
$min_verguetung = $output_interface['min_verguetung'];
$min_aufenthalt = $output_interface['min_aufenthalt'];
$restmenge = $output_interface['restmenge'];
$umrechnung = $output_interface['umrechnung'];
$eigenverdienst = $output_interface['eigenverdienst'];
$verguetungsoption = $output_interface['verguetungsoption'];
$eigenverdienst = $output_interface['eigenverdienst'];
$aufenthalt_zusatz = $output_interface['$aufenthalt_zusatz'];
$max_reload = $output_interface['max_reload'];
$restmenge = $output_interface['restmenge'];
$verhalten = $output_interface['verhalten'];

// extra vars for database values
$uid = '0';
$beschreibung = 'Allads4you Kampagne';
$mailtext = '';
$gueltig = '';

// Link öffnen
$fb=@fopen('http://www.allads4you.de/interface/?typ=forcedbanner&id='.$id_betreiber.'&sid='.$id_seite.'&pw='.$schnittstellencode.'&uebrig='.$restmenge.'&reload='.$max_reload.'&verguetung='.$min_verguetung.'','r');

// From here something works wrong and i cannot find the error

// standard vars to calculate
$file1 = "";
$file_fein = "";
$nummer = 0;
$spalten = 5;
$position = 0;
$einbuchen = true;

 if($fb){
 while($line=fgets($fb,1000)) {
 $file_fein.= $line;
    }
    fclose($fb);
}  // part to get data
$ausgabe     = explode("|", $file_fein);
$for_zaehler = (count($ausgabe)/$spalten)-1;
for ($zaehler=0;$zaehler <= $for_zaehler;$zaehler++) {
    $einbuchen          = true;
    //Reines einlesen vom Interface ANFANG
    $k_id             = (int)$ausgabe[$position];
    $k_tan            = md5('aa4y'.$k_id.'fb');
    $k_name           = addslashes($ausgabe[$position+1]);
    $k_reload         = (int)$ausgabe[$position+2]*3600;
    $k_menge          = (int)$ausgabe[$position+3];
    $verguetung_check = $ausgabe[$position+4];
    $verguetung_user  = round(($ausgabe[$position+4]*$umrechnung) - (($ausgabe[$position+4]*$umrechnung) / 100 * $eigenverdienst),2);
    $verguetung_webm  = round($ausgabe[$position+4]*$umrechnung,2);
    $k_banner_link    = "http://www.allads4you.de/codes/forcedbannerview.php?id=".$id_betreiber."&bid=".$ausgabe[$position]."&aid=".$id_seite."";
    $k_ziel_link       = "http://www.allads4you.de/codes/forcedbannerklick.php?id=".$id_betreiber."&bid=".$ausgabe[$position]."&aid=".$id_seite."";
    $k_aufenthalt       = $min_aufenthalt;
    //Reines einlesen vom Interface ENDE

//Prüfungsroutinen ANFANG only to check if the values are ok to put into database
    //Vergütung
    if($verguetung_webm >= $max_verguetung){
        if($verguetungsoption == '2'){
            $verguetung_webm = $max_verguetung;
            $verguetung_user  = round(($max_verguetung) - (($max_verguetung) / 100 * $eigenverdienst),2);
            $einbuchen = true;
        }else{
            $einbuchen = false;
        }
    }
    //Aufenthalt
    if($einbuchen == true){
        if($k_aufenthalt > $max_aufenthalt){
            $einbuchen = false;
        }
        if($einbuchen = true){
            if($k_aufenthalt < $min_aufenthalt){
                $k_aufenthalt = $min_aufenthalt;
            }
            $k_aufenthalt+= $aufenthalt_zusatz;
        }
    }
    //Reload
    if($einbuchen == true){
        if($k_reload > ($max_reload*3600)){
            $einbuchen = false;
        }elseif($k_reload == ''){
            $einbuchen = false;
        }elseif($k_reload == 0){
            //24 Stunden reload falls 0 Stunden Reload
            $k_reload = 86400;
        }
    }
    //Menge
    if($einbuchen == true){
        if($k_menge < $restmenge){
            $einbuchen = false;
        }
    }
    //Prüfungsroutinen ENDE
    //Vorberteiten für Ausgabe falls vorhanden ANFANG
    if($einbuchen == true){
        $nummer++;
    }
    if($verhalten <= '2' && $einbuchen == true){
        $anzeige.='<tr bgcolor="#90EE90">
                    <td align="center">'.$nummer.'</td>
                    <td align="center">'.$k_id.'</td>
                    <td align="right">'.number_format($verguetung_webm,2,",",".").'</td>
                    <td align="right">'.number_format($verguetung_user,2,",",".").'</td>
                    <td align="center">'.($k_reload/3600).'</td>
                    <td align="right">'.number_format($k_menge,0,",",".").'</td>
                    <td align="center">'.$k_aufenthalt.'</td>
                    <td>'.substr($k_name,0,64).'</td>
                      </tr>';
    }

//Vorbereiten für Ausgabe falls vorhanden ENDE
//Einbinden in die Datenbank falls eingestellt ANFANG
    if($verhalten >= '2' && $einbuchen == true){
        $vorhanden = db_query ("SELECT * FROM vms_gebuchte_werbung WHERE sponsor = 'allads4you' and `werbeart` = 'forcedbanner' and kid = '".$k_id."' LIMIT 1");
        if (mysql_num_rows($vorhanden) > 0){
            db_query ("UPDATE vms_gebuchte_werbung SET status = '1', banner = '".$k_banner_link."', ziel = '".$k_ziel_link."', menge = '".$k_menge."', preis = '".$verguetung_webm."', verdienst = '".$verguetung_user."', reload = '".$k_reload."', aufendhalt = '".$k_aufenthalt."' WHERE sponsor = 'allads4you' and `werbeart` = 'forcedbanner' and kid = '".$k_id."' and status = '0' LIMIT 1");
        }else{
// part to save data into database 
            db_query ("INSERT INTO vms_gebuchte_werbung (uid,tan,kid,ziel,banner,preis,verdienst,aufendhalt,menge,reload,sponsor,werbeart, status, beschreibung, mailtext, gueltig) VALUES ('".$uid."', '".$k_tan."','".$k_id."','".$k_ziel_link."','".$k_banner_link."','".$verguetung_webm."','".$verguetung_user."','".$k_aufenthalt."','".$k_menge."','".$k_reload."','allads4you','forcedbanner','".$status."','".$beschreibung."','".$mailtext."','".$gueltig."')");

      }

    }
    //Einbinden in die Datenbank falls eingestellt ENDE
    $position=$position+$spalten;
}



db_close();
?>
```

I read it many times if i forget and **;** or something like that but nothing .. can anyone give me some advice how to fix it ?

Comment: Too lengthy code to read. Did you tried printing your queries?

Comment: yes i did but i get only one result for id nothing else (1) .. im sorry for the length but i cannot find anything wrong so im a little confused cause in another way the code works perfect

Comment: sry missunderstood .. the querys from my database give me the right datas .. but i tried to get k_id and there i get only 1